# Change default admin password in ApacheDS

Tags: ldap, apacheds, ldif

Am new to ApacheDS - am using apacheds-2.0.0-M17.

The default password for admin is secret.

Does anyone know where I can change the value to something else?

Inside:

```
apacheds/instances/default/conf/config.ldif
```

Found the following entry:

```
ads-pwdattribute: userPassword
```

When googling it, there are a lot of examples that mention doing it using Apache Directory Studio but the particular instance I am trying to configure is running in a Linux shell in a headless (no UI) mode.

Tried using the following command with ldapmodify and the cursor hangs (keeps blinking) after pressing enter. I even tried prepending it with sudo and the same thing happens.

```
ldapmodify -H ldap://localhost:10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -x -w secret
```

Does anyone know why it hangs?

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Thanks again,

James

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the admin account password is documented i[n the ApacheDS documentation](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.2-changing-admin-password.html).

`ldapmodify`, if not given a file to process with `-f` parameter, waits for input from standard input, on which it expects a [LDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP_Data_Interchange_Format) formatted file with modifications to perform.

In your case such a LDIF file would look something like:

```
dn: uid=admin,ou=system
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: new-password
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you can still use Apache Directory Studio (or any other graphical LDAP client) to make this change, even if your directory is running on a headless server. LDAP is, after all, a network protocol. Just run the LDAP client on a local machine and connect over the network to your server. (Of course, I leave it to you to figure out if you have to open up some firewall rules or whatever.)

Answer (score 0):

```
dn: uid=admin,ou=system
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: new-password
-
```

After each modification, you need to add the end of "-"！！！