# ldap commands not recognized in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, ldap, apacheds

I am attempting to setup an LDAP server.

I installed ApacheDS and I was going through the user guide. I am trying to change the default admin password. I know I can use the Apache Directory Studio to do this, but I am required to use the command line to setup and maintain the LDAP server I create. 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221397/change-default-admin-password-in-apacheds) 
and it helped by showing how to use an ldif file to modify the default password.

However when I run

```
ldapmodify -h localhost -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -f conf-modify.ldif
```

I get the message:

```
'ldapmodify' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is there an LDAP package for windows command line tools or is there a specific directory that the ldap command must be executed from in ApacheDS

I am currently running the command from the ApacheDS install directory C:\Program Files\ApacheDS

Answer (score 0):

Open any cmd prompt and add add this command

**set path=%path%;E:\Softwares\OpenLDAP\bin**

and after that run your command

**ldapmodify -h localhost -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -f conf-modify.ldif**

I Hope it helps you.,

Answer (score 0):

An old article, perhaps still useful for ApacheDS users.

if you have found your bin folder with dsadm.exe usw.,
then you will find your ldapsearch.exe in a parallel folder.

```
dsee7:
*---bin
|       dsadm.exe
|
*---dsrk
    +---bin
        ldapsearch.exe
        ldapmodify.exe
```

WARNING:
call pls.

```
ldapmodify -h
```

In order to see the difference between openldap and ApacheDS.
It is not working with openldap syntax.
Have a fun with experimenting. (rulez Shadows)

Hint you will see the same syntax in suchlogs in your Apache Directory Browser